# SAX parser openStream() error

Tags: java, android, saxparser

Can you please tell me why does the **SAX** parser break on this line:

```
InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
```

Previously I have constructed url like this:

```
private String url = "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/image_of_the_day.rss";
```

URL is current and functional so it is not due to it.

I am new to SAX so please forgive me for my ignorance.

Here is the error log from Eclipse:

***11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.headfirstlabs.nasadailyimage/com.headfirstlabs.nasadailyimage.NasaDailyImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at com.headfirstlabs.nasadailyimage.IotdHandler.processFeed(IotdHandler.java:58)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at com.headfirstlabs.nasadailyimage.NasaDailyImage.onCreate(NasaDailyImage.java:18)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
11-30 20:27:24.892: E/AndroidRuntime(2388):     ... 11 more***

Comment: The line of code you posted has nothing to do with SAX. Add the error stacktrace to your question.

Comment: make sure device is connected to internet...

Comment: Thank you all, I am installing source code from Android in order to catch an error as Eclipse gives me "Source code unavailable" error if I try to look at the exception. I will contact you again when done

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exception that is thrown when you attempt to open the stream, and print out (at least) the exception message.  This should be sufficient to explain why the `openStream()` call isn't working.

(My guess would be either that your access to the site is blocked by a firewall, or you are *actually* attempting to connect to a different URL.  It is also possible that you have somehow got the wrong code line ...)

Comment: Thank you all, I am installing source code from Android in order to catch an error as Eclipse gives me "Source code unavailable" error if I try to look at the exception. I will contact you again when done.

Comment: OK; I found a solution. Look at this: http://oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=0636920012825

Answer (score 0):

I found out there is an error page about this book. (Very big one)
On page 105 it says that the parse method is missing a parameter.

You can have a look here:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=0636920012825